# javascript object manipulation: select properties according to specified condition

Tags: javascript, object

I have a javascript object of the following form:

```
{ url1: {status: "ok", updatedAt: someDate1},
  url2: {status: "error", updatedAt: someDate2},
  url3: {status: "error", updatedAt: someDate3},
  ...
}
```

I want to create a new object that contains all the elements which "status" property is "error".
In the example above I want the following object to be created:

```
  { url2: {status: "error", updatedAt: someDate2},
    url3: {status: "error", updatedAt: someDate3} 
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you need (`o` is your original object):

```
var errorObj = {};
for (k in o){
    var v = o[k];
    if (v.status === 'error'){
        errorObj[k] = v;
    }
}
```

Comment: simple and to-the point. Also, you answered faster than I did, although I went the generic route.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I thought, just wanted to make sure I'm not missing a more "elegant" solution (like c# linq)

Answer (score 4):

Iterate over all properties and copy over the objects that match?

```
function filterByProperty(obj, predicate) {
   var selected={};
   for (p in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p) && predicate(obj[p])) {
         selected[p] = obj[p];
      } 
   }
   return selected;
}
```

And call using

```
filterByProperty(object, function(o) {o.status === "error";});
```

I love passing functions as arguments...